# Bluetooth stopped working suddenly

Tags: 14.10, bluetooth, troubleshooting

I am not able to see `bluetooth` symbol on the `panel`. 
I checked with `Unity Tweak Tool` and there is a tick mark for bluetooth.

Further, I ran the command `sudo service bluetooth status` and it gave `bluetooth start/running, process 744`

```
tasdik@Acer:~/Dropbox/code$ rfkill list
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

And

```
tasdik@Acer:~/Dropbox/code$ sudo bluetoothd -d -n
bluetoothd[18809]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
bluetoothd[18809]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing main.conf
bluetoothd[18809]: src/main.c:parse_config() discovto=0
bluetoothd[18809]: src/main.c:parse_config() pairto=0
bluetoothd[18809]: src/main.c:parse_config() pageto=8192
bluetoothd[18809]: src/main.c:parse_config() auto_to=60
bluetoothd[18809]: src/main.c:parse_config() name=%h-%d
bluetoothd[18809]: src/main.c:parse_config() class=0x000100
bluetoothd[18809]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DeviceID'
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[18809]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

Because of it I am not able to transfer files between my PC and mobile devices.

Any ideas guys?

**Edit :** **Tried some more things, gave me these**

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c00 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             446190  10 bnep,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
```

And

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    1.779150] usb 1-1.4: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   22.545624] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   22.545650] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.545661] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.545666] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.545682] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.553720] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.553725] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.553734] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   22.594494] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   22.594510] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   22.594517] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

And

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.164868] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query honored via cmdline
[    1.907636] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x461f00)
```

And

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Edit :**

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | grep -iA7 Vendor=413c
tasdik@Acer:~$
```

Tried the above but it returned nothing.

I will add the result of what I got before the piping

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices 

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 2
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 3.16
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.16.0-33-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 8
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev= 0.00
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   2 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 2
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 3.16
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.16.0-33-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev= 0.00
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   1 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1bcf ProdID=2c00 Rev= 8.12
S:  Manufacturer=C8BAJ0ARE
S:  Product=1.3M HD WebCam
C:* #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
A:  FirstIf#= 0 IfCount= 2 Cls=0e(video) Sub=03 Prot=00
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=87(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=16ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 192 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 2 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 384 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 3 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 512 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 4 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 640 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 5 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 800 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 6 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 944 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 7 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=1280 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 8 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=1600 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 9 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=1984 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt=10 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=2880 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt=11 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=3060 Ivl=125us
```

**EDIT :**

I don't know what happened but this time `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` gave 6 devices.

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 2
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 3.16
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.16.0-33-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 8
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev= 0.00
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   2 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 2
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  2, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 3.16
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.16.0-33-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev= 0.00
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   1 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=1.5  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=2107 Rev= 1.15
S:  Manufacturer=Dell
S:  Product=Dell USB Entry Keyboard
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=10ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1bcf ProdID=2c00 Rev= 8.12
S:  Manufacturer=C8BAJ0ARE
S:  Product=1.3M HD WebCam
C:* #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
A:  FirstIf#= 0 IfCount= 2 Cls=0e(video) Sub=03 Prot=00
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=87(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=16ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 192 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 2 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 384 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 3 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 512 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 4 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 640 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 5 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 800 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 6 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 944 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 7 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=1280 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 8 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=1600 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 9 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=1984 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt=10 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=2880 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt=11 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=3060 Ivl=125us
tasdik@Acer:~$
```

And further

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ dmesg | grep -e Atheros -e Broadcom
[    1.779163] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[   20.115324] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9485 Rev:1 mem=0xffffc90021600000, irq=17
```

Well `hciconfig -a` gave nothing. Ditto without the `-a` flag too.

```
tasdik@Acer:~$ hciconfig -a
tasdik@Acer:~$
```

**EDIT:**

I had a software update(ubuntu base), so restarted the system and then did the

`dmesg > Desktop/dmesg.txt`

[Here is the pastebin link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10778133/)

**EDIT:**

I added the modules to the kernel through the command

`sudo modprobe ath3k` and `sudo modprobe btusb`
 but when I tried opening the GUI "bluetooth" from settings It shows `no adapters found`

There was no `bluetooth` indicator showing after I tried the above, but there are some changes from before when I did the following.

```
tasdik@Acer:~/Dropbox/code/java$ lsmod | grep -i bluetooth
bluetooth             446190  12 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
```

Comment: There have been some changes in the kernel, so can you add the result of `lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; rfkill list all` to the question

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for the suggestion, hope the updated question helps.

Comment: Can't find much but I have a hunch `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | grep -iA7 Vendor=413c`

Comment: updated it, thanks for your patience. I hope we solve it :D

Comment: Strange that 6 devices show in `lsusb` but only 5 show in /usb/devices.  Add the result from `dmesg | grep -e Atheros -e Broadcom; hciconfig -a`

Comment: Can you paste your entire `dmesg` to paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL?  It shows an Atheros device on usb 1-1.4 that is a bluetooth host controller from the first dmesg  but for some reason there is no trace of an Atheros device in lsusb

Comment: Try loading the modules manually `sudo modprobe ath3k` and `sudo modprobe btusb`  The bluetooth modules did show in the dmesg as a 04ca:3004 Atheros bluetooth